# How to style the items in PrimeVue's Dataview differently in List and Grid mode?

Tags: css, vuejs3, styling, primevue

When switching from list to grid mode in [PrimeVue's DataView](https://primevue.org/dataview), the following changes happen in the DOM:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why in both display modes, **the direct parent of the items to be displayed in the Dataview is a grid**. Only the grandparent div changes its class.

In List mode I would like to use **a different flex display than in Grid mode.** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I found a working solution:

```
.p-dataview-list :deep( .p-grid) {
    // my stlye
}
```

In my previous attempts, I was using deep() the wrong way.